# Where does Coinify get its Bitcoins, and can I track their exchange rate somewhere?

Tags: exchanges, trading, tracking

I have not found anything in their FAQ. As I understand, you can buy BTC from BTC exchanges, a place where buyers and sellers meet and agree on some price.

- If I buy BTC through Coinify, where do they get them? They only list a BTC price on their front page but no source whatsoever.
- Provided there is some exchange they use, where can I track the Euro/BTC exchange rate?
- Do I have to make multiple accounts for each exchange with the entire verification stuff each time I want to get my BTC somewhere else?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bitcoin_companies#cite_note-coinify-1-7), they use Coinjar. Why wouldn't they list this on their website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked them in an email and they provided me with the following response:

> ... we use a Volume-Weighted Average Price (VWAP) over multiple
>   exchanges (not CoinJar though as the Wikipedia article said) to get an
>   average rate that reflects most of the BTC exchange rate market.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume-weighted_average_price

and

> ...each order you make will be processed with the best exchange rate we
>   can find at the moment.